# SwiperJS causing issues with bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css

Im trying to combine [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/) and [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/); trying to make each item in a Bootstrap grid have a paginator for some text. The issue I'm having is that the columns are for some reason all taking 100% width.
Using bootstrap 5

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper1", {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  loop: true,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
});
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper2", {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  loop: true,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
});
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper3", {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  loop: true,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
});
```

```css
.past-projects {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.past-projects h1 {
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.past-projects .row .project {
  width: 300px;
}

.past-projects .row .project img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 3px solid #4b4b4b;
}

.past-projects .row .project .text {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  color: white;
}

.discord {
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.discord a {
  margin-top: 20px !important;
  margin-right: 10px !important;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.swiper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="bg-dark">
  <div class="past-projects">
    <h1 class="ps-1 text-white mx-auto text-center">Past Projects</h1>
    <div class="row g-4">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="project mx-auto">
          <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/thumbnail-image-vector-graphic-vector-id1147544807?k=20&m=1147544807&s=612x612&w=0&h=pBhz1dkwsCMq37Udtp9sfxbjaMl27JUapoyYpQm0anc=" alt="">
          <div class="text">
            <p class="title">BloxRoyale</p>
            <div class="swiper swiper1">
              <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <p class="swiper-slide">ENG SLO GR</p>
                <p class="swiper-slide">SP RU FP</p>
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
              <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="project mx-auto">
            <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/thumbnail-image-vector-graphic-vector-id1147544807?k=20&m=1147544807&s=612x612&w=0&h=pBhz1dkwsCMq37Udtp9sfxbjaMl27JUapoyYpQm0anc=" alt="">
            <div class="text">
              <p class="title">BloxRoyale</p>
              <div class="swiper swiper2">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                  <p class="swiper-slide">ENG SLO GR</p>
                  <p class="swiper-slide">SP RU FP</p>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="project mx-auto">
            <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/thumbnail-image-vector-graphic-vector-id1147544807?k=20&m=1147544807&s=612x612&w=0&h=pBhz1dkwsCMq37Udtp9sfxbjaMl27JUapoyYpQm0anc=" alt="">
            <div class="text">
              <p class="title">BloxRoyale</p>
              <div class="swiper swiper3">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                  <p class="swiper-slide">ENG SLO GR</p>
                  <p class="swiper-slide">SP RU FP</p>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
        loop: true,  
        spaceBetween:24,
        grabCursor: true,        
        pagination: {
          el: ".swiper-pagination",
          dynamicBullets: true,
        },
        breakpoints: {    
          768: {
            slidesPerView: 1,        
          },
          1024: {  
            slidesPerView: 3,             
            spaceBetween: 48,
          },
        },
      });
```

Comment: And what is it?

Comment: i also running issue with swiper and bootstrap 5, I use this code and it's worked for me!